# Date formating by clicking ImageView in Android

Tags: android, datepicker

I am new to use Date picker in android

I have an `ImageView` (which is looks like a calender image) by clicking on that `ImageView`  have to give selection of (MONTH/DATE/YEAR) date and that Selected date should be display in a `EditText`by default this `EditText` Should contains Tomorrow's Date

Any help please.........

Comment: any XML or JAVA code which you have try ?

Comment: go through the documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html